# Method to Decompose Modulation Series

Tags: decomposition

Given a signal $$\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{\sin(2\pi/Tx)x}\right)+n$$ (where n is noise) is there a way to isolate and decompose the number, frequency, and causal (carrier-modulator) order of the oscillators (here 2)?

(Similar to [How do I find amplitude modulation effects in natural signals](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30391/how-do-i-find-amplitude-modulation-effects-in-natural-signals) but more formal).

Comment: The equation you gave seems to be constant. Can you clarify what the signal is?

Comment: @MBaz Sorry, I forgot x. Also added a noise parameter to the signal. (Random fluctuations are expected.)

Comment: Are you sure $x$ appears in the denominator? That is unusual. Could you also include the statistics of $n$ (distribution,mean, etc)?

Comment: @MBaz What I'm trying to illustrate is a function `f(x)=sin(2pi/Tx)` where the input `x` is essentially the same function `f(x)`, but with a different value for T. (One sine wave oscilator modulating another sine wave... generalized to n sine waves) I would assume that the noise is poisson distributed. Alternatively, the noise can be reduced by averaging multiple segments of similar signals (common mode rejection) or it can be treated as a residual (and simply ignored for an 'ideal' analytical solution).

Comment: @MBaz My maths is not so good. Sorry about that.